# Best way to auto append command argument

Tags: shell

While on my mac, I use csshx to login to a number of different hosts at the same time. Due to the security set up, I need to use a jump host for every login attempt, my command looks like this:

```
csshx <some hosts> --ssh_args "-o LogLevel=error -A -t <jump host> -l <user> /user/local/bin/ssh $1"
```

It works but I have to do reverse lookup every time I want to use csshx. Is there a way I can have everything after --ssh_args automatically appended as I type my command? I tried to do something in my .profile file like this

```
function csshxq(){    
cssh $* --ssh_args "-o LogLevel=error -A -t <jump host> -l <user> /user/local/bin/ssh $*"
}
```

But when I try to run `csshxq <hosts>` it will actually login to the first host on the list n times, where n is the number of elements in the list.

Anyone have good suggestions to create this lazy shortcut?

Comment: nice idea, but you have `$*` twice in your command line. You have to delimit the hosts and the real command. Can you post a real example with hostnames and a command?

Comment: I also had tried `cssh $* --ssh_args "-o LogLevel=error -A -t jumphost1.example.com -l dum /user/local/bin/ssh $1"`and it gives me the same result